# Incorrect syntax near ')'. in variable declaration of sql

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2, syntax-error

I have following query:

```
DECLARE @userrole as VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @userrole = UserRole 
FROM UserMenuRights 
WHERE idAdmin = 36

Execute('Select idRole,RoleName from UserRoles WHERE idRole IN ('+@userrole+')')
```

I am getting the error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

I have checked in first line `DECLARE @userrole as VARCHAR(100)` seems no where syntax problem.

Also checked with final line :

```
Execute('Select idRole,RoleName from UserRoles WHERE idRole IN ('+@userrole+')')
```

Also seemed correct string attachment.

Where have I made a mistake?

Please help me.

Comment: what is datatype of field `idRole` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, you need to add single quote

```
DECLARE @userrole as VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @userrole =UserRole FROM UserMenuRights WHERE idAdmin =36
Execute('Select idRole,RoleName from UserRoles WHERE idRole IN ('''+@userrole+''')')
```

OR you construct it like this

```
SELECT  idRole
        ,RoleName
FROM    UserRoles
WHERE   idRole IN (
            SELECT UserRole FROM UserMenuRights WHERE idAdmin =36
            )
```

Comment: To add a bit of explanation, you delcared userrole as a varchar, those extra quotes as suggested by jade is to escape single quotes within the quoted command in execute()

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @userrole as VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @userrole =UserRole FROM UserMenuRights WHERE idAdmin =36

-- Use sp_executesql instead
DECLARE @Statement NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Statement = N'SELECT idRole, RoleName FROM UserRoles WHERE idRole = @UserRole'

EXEC sp_executesql @statement, N'@UserRole varchar(100)', @UserRole
```